# Can't find thread.py

Tags: python

What does this code mean?

```
try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    del _sys.modules[__name__]#why
    raise
```

But I can't find thread.py.

why,`del _sys.modules[__name__]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code from Python's `threading.py` is trying to load the C implementation of the `thread` module.  If it fails (for some reason this hasn't been compiled, as it would be with all Python distributions) then it deletes itself from the list of modules so that `threading` doesn't show up as having been imported.

If you're looking for the source of the `thread` module, it's here: http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Python/thread.c

Answer (score 0):

Must be some custom logic - keeping track of what is imported and where. In regular Python 3.1 this standalone code does not work:

```
>>> try:
    import thread
except:
    del _sys.modules[__name__]
    raise

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 4, in <module>
    del _sys.modules[__name__]
NameError: name '_sys' is not defined
>>>
```

Where did you find this?